# Strings for Calculator

Tags: java, string, addition, calculator

I want to write a calculator that takes the numbers from text fields and adds them together to give them out in a text area.
It works as far as taking the two numbers from the text fields, but when I add them together it will give out: `1+1=11`.

How can I add the two strings so it will equal 2?

This is my source code:

```
private void ButtonPlusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String Nummer1 = Zahl1.getText();
    String Nummer2 = Zahl2.getText();

    int intZahl1 = Integer.parseInt(Nummer1);
    Integer integerZahl1 = new Integer(Nummer1);

            int intZahl2 = Integer.parseInt(Nummer2);
    Integer integerZahl2 = new Integer(Nummer2);

    Result.setText(Nummer1 + Nummer2);
```

`Result` is the name of my text area and the divers `Nummer`s are just variables, as you may have noticed already.

Comment: Besides @HovercraftFullOfEels' answer, I wanted to point out that Java coding conventions state that package names are all lower case, class names are CamelCase beginning with an Upper Case letter, and variable names are camelCase beginning with a lower case letter.  All that to say, you should declare your variables `Nummer1` & `Nummer2` as `nummer1` & `nummer2`, even though I know nouns are all capitalized auf Deutsch so it isn't as intuitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the Strings not the ints. You will want to add integerZahl1 and intZahl2 instead of Nummer1 and Nummer2.

For example,

```
int intResult = intZahl1 + intZahl2;
Result.setText(String.valueOf(intResult));
```

Also as an aside, you'll want to learn and follow Java naming conventions. Variable and method names should start with a lower-case letter, and class names should start with an upper-case letter.

---

Dom states:

> Or you could just do Result.setText(intZahl1 + intZahl2); if you only need to display the result.

Dom, please understand that `setText(...)` requires a String parameter, not an int, so your method call will not be allowed by the compiler.  If one tries the trick of

```
Result.setText("" + intZahl + intZahl2);
```

they'd get `11` again. For your technique to work, you'd need to do something like,

```
Result.setText(String.valueOf(intZahl1 + intZahl2));
```

---

Edit

Also you will want to use ints and not Integers.

Comment: shouldn't it be `int intResult = intZahl1 + intZahl2;`?

Comment: No problem, we all have D'oh moments :)

Comment: Or you could just do  `Result.setText(intZahl1 + intZahl2);` if you only need to display the result.

Comment: @Dom: Your recommendation has a flaw. Please see edit to answer.